# SQL Anywhere 10 - Can you combine cache control commands?

Tags: sqlanywhere

So this may seem like a silly question but I have been unable to find documentation that supports either side of the question.

SQL Anywhere 10 - dbsrv10.exe has numerous startup options.  I'm being told by some near me that the service can not combine cache specific command line options.

A specific example would be:

dbsrv10.exe -c 50M would set the initial cache size to 50 MB

dbsrv10.exe -ch 500M would set the max cache size to 500MB

It would make sense to me that I would want and be able to control both the initial and max cache values and use the startup string that combined both switches.

dbsrv10.exe -c 50M -ch 500M and get both an initial value and a max value configured with the startup of this db instance.

I'm working on getting some confirmation from Sybase themselves but while I wait I figured I would throw it out to anyone on here that might be using SQLAnywhere.

Can I combine the -c and -ch startup options when launching dbsrv10.exe? Is anyone doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify more than one of the cache control switches. Using both -c and -ch is quite common for just the reasons you describe.